# How to redirect to new blog post in React/Django

Tags: reactjs, django, forms, fetch

I'm building a blog site with React/Django. Here's my basic NewBlog component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function NewBlog(props) {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [body, setBody] = useState('')
    
    function postBlog() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/blogs/', {
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json",
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "title": title,
                "author": 1,
                "body": body
            }),
            "method":"POST",
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={postBlog}>
            <textarea className='title' placeholder='title...' onChange={(ev) => setTitle(ev.target.value)} value={title}></textarea>
            <textarea className='body' placeholder='' onChange={(ev) => setBody(ev.target.value)} value={body}></textarea>
            <button>POST</button>
            </form>
            <div>
                <Link to='/blog'>BACK</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NewBlog;
```

This works to POST a new blog, but after I submit the form, I can't figure out how to redirect to that specific blog, which would just be `http://localhost:8000/blogs/BLOG_ID`. Instead, the form is just cleared, and I have to go `<Link to='/blog'>BACK</Link>` to the BlogList to see the new blog rendered.

Now, I know with Django you can use their form to post a blog, and, once posted, it redirects to that `blog_detail`. My issue is I don't know how to do that using React on the front end. Is there some kind of Redirect or Route I can use? Also, I'm not sure how I'd even retrieve that just-posted blog's id either.

Sorry if this isn't a lot to go on, I don't know what other piece of my code I could show that would help the question seeing as the logic works to post a blog, I just can't get to that specific blog after post.

Comment: After sending the request to `http://localhost:8000/api/blogs/`, does the response include the blog ID?

Comment: no the response is empty.

Comment: Can you make the response provide the blog ID?

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to make the post request output the new blog object that just got created with its id.

```
{
    id: #,
    ...

}
```

so then you could just use the `useNavigate` hook from react-router-dom and go to that page

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function NewBlog(props) {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [body, setBody] = useState('')
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    
    function postBlog() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/blogs/', {
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json",
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "title": title,
                "author": 1,
                "body": body
            }),
            "method":"POST",
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          navigate(`/blog/${data.id}`) 
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={postBlog}>
            <textarea className='title' placeholder='title...' onChange={(ev) => setTitle(ev.target.value)} value={title}></textarea>
            <textarea className='body' placeholder='' onChange={(ev) => setBody(ev.target.value)} value={body}></textarea>
            <button>POST</button>
            </form>
            <div>
                <Link to='/blog'>BACK</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NewBlog;
```

Comment: what do you mean post request output? Cause right now the response is still blank.

Comment: Update your route and make it send the blog object that just got created.

Comment: I guess my issue there is I don't really know what you mean. You mean in my django backend?

Comment: Yes. If possible, edit the post route `http://localhost:8000/api/blogs/` so that it sends back a blog object with its id.

Comment: still don't understand where I'm editing the route, like in which .py file.

Comment: How am I suppose to know which py file..? As I said, the post route `http://localhost:8000/api/blogs/`.